# Mysql Function - not sure where to start

Tags: mysql, function, cursor

I would like to write a function in Mysql that from a given product code return a formatted string

Here is an example of the calls I need to manually make now to get the result I want.

```
SELECT p.productcategoryid from products p where (isnull(p.endeffdt) or (p.endeffdt = '0000-00-00') or (p.endeffdt > now())) and p.code='T29R66N1';
```

T29R66NQ is the product code I need the full path for - the above call returns '38' as the category ID.

I then perform the following select based on the result from above

```
SELECT name,parentid,productcategorypath FROM productcategory WHERE recid = '38';
```

This returns

name->Built-In Hobs
parentid->7
productcategorypath=222,7,38

Using that result I then

```
SELECT name,parentid,productcategorypath FROM productcategory WHERE recid = '7';
```

giving me

name->Built-In
parentid->222
productcategorypath=222,7

and again, I then do

```
SELECT name,parentid,productcategorypath FROM productcategory WHERE recid = '222';
```

which in turn gives me

name->Kitchen & Home Appliances
parentid->0
productcategorypath=222

I stop there because parentid = 0 (it may go on for more iterations but will always end with parent id of 0) but i need the results from the last 3 selects to give me the following string

```
Kitchen & Home Appliances > Built-In  > Built-In Hobs
```

I would like a mysql function whereby I can use it like

```
select getpath(code) from products where code='T29R66N1'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I managed to figure it myself - here is my function

> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS mydb.getpath;
>
> CREATE FUNCTION mydb.getpath (itemid VARCHAR(20))
>
> RETURNS varchar(255)
>
> BEGIN
>
> DECLARE path_name varchar(255);
>   DECLARE tmp_name varchar(255);
>   DECLARE tmp_parentid INT;
>   DECLARE tmp_parentid1 INT;
>
> SELECT p.productcategoryid INTO tmp_parentid from products p where (isnull(p.endeffdt) or (p.endeffdt = '0000-00-00') or (p.endeffdt > now())) and p.code=itemid;
>
> myloop:LOOP
>
> > SELECT name,parentid INTO tmp_name,tmp_parentid1 FROM productcategory WHERE recid = tmp_parentid;
> >     SET path_name = concat_ws(' > ', tmp_name,path_name);
> >     IF tmp_parentid1!=0 THEN
> >      SET tmp_parentid = tmp_parentid1;
> >      ITERATE myloop;
> >     ELSE
> >      LEAVE myloop;
> >     END IF; 
> >     END LOOP;
>
> RETURN path_name;
>
> END;

Comment: The structure you are using is called an *adjacency list*.  Here's a reference to get you started: http://ulaptech.blogspot.ca/2010/05/retrieving-data-hierarchies-on-sql.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS mydb.getpath;

CREATE FUNCTION mydb.getpath (itemid VARCHAR(20))

RETURNS varchar(255) 

BEGIN

DECLARE path_name varchar(255);
DECLARE tmp_name varchar(255);
DECLARE tmp_parentid INT;
DECLARE tmp_parentid1 INT;

SELECT p.productcategoryid INTO tmp_parentid from products p where (isnull(p.endeffdt) or (p.endeffdt = '0000-00-00') or (p.endeffdt > now())) and p.code=itemid;

myloop:LOOP

SELECT name,parentid INTO tmp_name,tmp_parentid1 FROM productcategory WHERE recid = tmp_parentid;
SET path_name = concat_ws(' > ', tmp_name,path_name);
IF tmp_parentid1!=0 THEN
SET tmp_parentid = tmp_parentid1;
ITERATE myloop;
ELSE
LEAVE myloop;
END IF; 
END LOOP;


RETURN path_name;


END;
```